# Problems attempting to emulate a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I was attempting to emulate Promise functionality, for backward compatibility, and I ran into some issues. Really, it just left me wondering how to accomplish that type of functionality. You know, where a function is passed as an argument, then the function arguments are executed. Consider the Promise pattern:

```
new Promise(function(function(){}, function(){}){});
```

So, it's clear the pattern I seek is a function that takes at least one function, in my case, and is able to execute it's argument.

I tried

```
function testFunc(anotherFunc){
  return anotherFunc(anotherFunc.arguments[0]());
}
console.log(testFunc(function(function(){ return 'help'; }){}));
```

with no success. How would I go about this? I'm just stumped.

Comment: Maybe it is better to take a look at [Promise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) or even use it?

Comment: Just trying to understand the concept of passing a function as an argument that has a function as its argument, and execute the function that is an argument of another function.

Comment: what does "with no success" mean, exactly? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example, I've renamed functions to match Promise naming conventions more closely.

```js
function promiseFunc(executor) {
    executor(function (data) {
        console.log('Promise is resolved', data);
    }, function (error) {
        console.error('Promise is rejected', error);
    })
}

promiseFunc(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            resolve('some result');
        } else {
            reject(new Error('some error'));
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

It will call resolve / reject randomly just for demonstration purposes

Comment: Thanks. I think I finally get Promise. Take a look at my answer to see if you object.

Comment: @PHPglue actually your solution will cause additional load for the browser because of `setInterval`. Imagine that your application creates 10000 promises - it will mean 10000*16 calls to your handlers per animation frame that is way too much

Comment: @PHPglue yes, looks better now :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
function Fulfill(fulfillDenyFunc){
  var t = this, df = [];
  this.fulfilled = false;
  fulfillDenyFunc(function(){
    for(var i=0,l=df.length; i<l; i++){
      df[i]();
    }
    t.fulfilled = true;
  }, function(){
    t.fulfilled = false;
  });
  this.then = function(doFunc){
    if(this.fulfilled){
      doFunc();
    }
    else{
      df.push(doFunc);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
onload = function(){
var ff = new Fulfill(function(yup, nope){
  if(yup){
    console.log('starting');
    setTimeout(function(){
      yup();
    }, 4000);
  }
  else{
    nope();
  }
});
var what = {just:'trying', to:'slow', down:'then'};
setTimeout(function(){
  ff.then(function(){
    console.log('showing use of .then() after another Asychronous function');
  });
}, 5000);
}
```